# Lemma of dévissage from Mumford's AGII

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, abelian-categories, coherent-sheaves

In Mumford's & Oda's [Algebraic Geometry II](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Algebraic%20Geometry%20II%20%28a%20penultimate%20draft%29), on page 81 the authors give a proof for 6.12: Lemma of dévissage.
After a careful reading of the proof, I failed to understand an argument:

> **Theorem 6.12** (“Lemma of dévissage”)**.** *Let $\mathbf K$ be the abelian category of coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules
> on a noetherian scheme $X$, and $\mathbf K’\subset\operatorname{Ob}(\mathbf K)$ an exact subset. We have $\mathbf K’=\operatorname{Ob}(\mathbf K)$,
> if for any closed irreducible subset $Y\subset X$ with generic point $y$ there exists an coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathcal{G}\in\mathbf K’$ with support
> $Y$ such that  $\mathcal{G}_y$  is a one-dimensional $\mathbb k(y)$-vector space.*

About *exact subset*: Let $\mathbf K$ be an abelian category, and denote by $\operatorname{Ob}(\mathbf K)$ the set of its objects.
A subset $\mathbf K’\subset\operatorname{Ob}(\mathbf K)$ is said to be *exact* if $0\in\mathbf K’$ and if the following is satisfied: In an exact
sequence $0\to A’\to A\to A’’\to 0$ in $\mathbf K$, if two among $A$, $A’$ and $A’’$ belong to $\mathbf K’$, then the third also
belongs to $\mathbf K’$.

We continue with the proof:

> **Proof.** For simplicity, a closed subset $Y\subset X$ is said to have property $\mathbf P(Y)$ if any $\mathcal{S}\in\operatorname{Ob}(\mathbf K)$ with $\operatorname{Supp}(\mathcal{S})\subset Y$ satisfies $\mathcal{S}\in\mathbf K’$.
> We need to show that $X$ has property $\mathbf P(X)$.
> By noetherian induction, it suffices to show that a closed subset $Y\subset X$ has property $\mathbf P(Y)$
> if any closed subset $Y’\subsetneqq X$ has property $\mathbf P(Y’)$.
> Thus we now show $\mathcal{F} ∈ $ Ob(**K**) satisfies $\mathcal{F}\in\mathbf K’$ if $\operatorname{Supp}(\mathcal{F})\subset Y$. Endow $Y$ with the unique
> structure of closed reduced subscheme $Y_{\mathrm{red}}$ of $X$ with the ideal sheaf $\mathcal{J}$. Since $\mathcal{J}\supset\operatorname{Ann}(\mathcal{F})$ (???), there
> exists $n > 0$ such that $\mathcal{J}^n\mathcal{F} = (0)$. Looking at successive quotients in the filtration ...

**Q.** Why $\mathcal{J}\supset\operatorname{Ann}(\mathcal{F})$? I don't understand the logic behind the argument.

Recall the definitions.  $\operatorname{Supp}(\mathcal{F})= \{x \in X\mid\mathcal{F}_x \neq 0 \}$ and $\operatorname{Ann}(\mathcal{F})_x = \{r \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \mid \forall f \in \mathcal{F}_x,\, r \cdot f =0 \}$.

We need to show that $\forall x \in X$ we have an inclusion $\mathcal{J}_x\supset \operatorname{Ann}(\mathcal{F})_x$ of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$-modules.
If $x \not \in Y$ it's trivial because in that case $\mathcal{J}_x= \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$.

The case  $ x \in Y$ I don't understand. Assume for example that $\mathcal{F}_x=0$.
This means that $\operatorname{Ann}(\mathcal{F})_x= \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$.
Otherwise because $ x \in Y$ we obtain $\mathcal{J}_x \neq \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$, a contradiction.

Do I miss any additional assumption on $Y$?

Comment: It should read $\mathcal{J} \subset Ann(\mathcal{F})$. This holds since $Supp(\mathcal{F}) = V(Ann(\mathcal{F})) \subset V(\mathcal{J})$.

Comment: @random123:yes, $Supp(\mathcal{F}) ⊂ Y$ imply $\mathcal{J} \subset Ann(\mathcal{F})$. are you sure that this is really what the author wanted to say? this confuses me because in the next sentence the author says that this imply $\mathcal{J}^n\mathcal{F} = (0)$ for *certain* $n >0$. on the other hand $\mathcal{J} \subset Ann(\mathcal{F})$ would give a much stonger statement that $\mathcal{J}\mathcal{F} = (0)$.

Comment: the "certain $n>0$" confuses me since if we continue to work with "wrong" inclusion $\mathcal{J} ⊃ Ann(\mathcal{F})$ then since $\mathcal{J}$ is radical ideal we conclude $\mathcal{J} =\sqrt{\mathcal{J}} ⊃ \sqrt{Ann(\mathcal{F})} = \bigcap_{\mathfrak{p} \in supp(\mathcal{F})} \mathfrak{p} ⊃\bigcap_{\mathfrak{p} \in V(\mathcal{J})} \mathfrak{p}= \sqrt{\mathcal{J}}$ and therefore becuase $X$ noetherian we obtain $\mathcal{J}^n\mathcal{F} = (0)$ for *certain* $n>0$.

Comment: in some way $\mathcal{J} ⊃ Ann(\mathcal{F})$ underlines that this $n$ exists but it might be not $n=1$ in general. I think that the author wanted to say $\mathcal{J} = \sqrt{\mathcal{J}} \subset \sqrt{Ann(\mathcal{F})}$. then it make sense with "certain" $n>0$

Comment: What you say in the last comment is correct. It follows from what I wrote in the comment and the fact that $I(V(I))= rad(I)$.