# Devissage lemma part 2 (by Mumford's & Oda's AG II)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

This question is part II of my proof reading of [Lemma of devissage](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3372507/lemma-of-devissage-from-mumfords-agii)
from Mumford's & Oda's [Algebraic Geometry II](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Algebraic%20Geometry%20II%20%28a%20penultimate%20draft%29), findable on page 81; Theorem  6.12:

> Theorem 6.12 (“Lemma of devissage”). Let $K$ be the abelian category of coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$ modules
>   on a noetherian scheme $X$, and K′ $\subset$ Ob(**K**) an exact subset. We have **K′** $=$ Ob(**K**),
>   if for any closed irreducible subset $Y ⊂ X$ with generic point $y$ there exists an coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$ module $\mathcal{G} ∈ $ **K′** with support
>   $Y$ such that  $\mathcal{G}_y$  is a one-dimensional $k(y)$-vector space.

Few comments on *exact subset*. Let **K** be an abelian category, and denote by Ob(**K**) the set of its objects.
A subset **K′** $\subset$ Ob(**K**) is called exact if $0 ∈$ **K′** and if the following is satisfied: in an exact
sequence $0 → A′ → A → A′′ → 0$ in **K**, if two among $A, A′$ and $A′′$ belong to **K′**, then the third also
belongs to **K′**.

We continue with the proof:

> **Proof**. For simplicity, a closed subset $Y ⊂ X$ is said to have property **P**($Y$) if any $\mathcal{S} ∈$
>   Ob(**K**) with $Supp(\mathcal{S}) ⊂ Y$ satisfies $\mathcal{S} ∈ $ **K′**.
>   We need to show that X has property **P**($X$).
>   By noetherian induction, it suffices to show that a closed subset $Y ⊂ X$ has property **P**($Y$)
>   if any closed subset $Y′ ⫋ Y$ has property **P**($Y'$).
>   Thus we now show $\mathcal{F} ∈ $ Ob(**K**) satisfies $\mathcal{F} ∈ $ **K′** if $Supp(\mathcal{F}) ⊂ Y$. Endow $Y$ with the unique
>   structure of closed reduced subscheme $Y_{red}$ of $X$ with the ideal sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ . Since $\mathcal{J} = \sqrt{\mathcal{J}} \subset \sqrt{Ann(\mathcal{F})}$, there
>   exists $n > 0$ such that $\mathcal{J}^n\mathcal{F} = (0)$. Looking at successive quotients in the filtration $$ \mathcal{F} ⊃ \mathcal{J} \mathcal{F} ⊃ \mathcal{J}^2 \mathcal{F} ⊃ ... ⊃ \mathcal{J}^{n-1} \mathcal{F} ⊃ \mathcal{J}^n \mathcal{F} = (0) $$ we may assume $n = 1$, that is, $\mathcal{J} \mathcal{F} = (0)$, in view of the exactness of **K′**. (**???**) Let $j : Y → X$ be the
>   closed immersion so that $\mathcal{F} = j_*j^*\mathcal{F}$.

Q: Why does the exactness of **K′** allow us to reduce to the case $n = 1$, i.e.  that $\mathcal{J} \mathcal{F} = (0)$? What is the argument which allows to perform this reduction?

In addition I would like to remark that I asked this question some time ago in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/343085/devissage-lemma-mumfords-odas-ag-ii).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have proven the case $n=1$. The authors claim that by induction on $n$, one may prove that every $\mathcal{G}$ in $\mathbf{K}$ with support in $Y$ and verifying $\mathcal{J}^n\mathcal{G}=0$ is in $\mathbf{K}'$.

The first step of the induction is given by the $n=1$ case. Then, assume that the step $n-1$ has been proven and take a $\mathcal{G}$ as above. From step $n-1$ you get that $\mathcal{JG}$ is in $\mathbf{K}'$ and since $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{JF}$ is killed by $\mathcal{J}$, the step $n=1$ tells you that $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{JF}\in\mathbf{K}'$. Thus, you have an exact sequence $0\rightarrow\mathcal{JF}\rightarrow \mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{JF}\rightarrow0$ where the kernel and the cokernel are in $\mathbf{K}'$: the exactness of $\mathbf{K}'$ tells you that $\mathcal{F}$ is also in $\mathbf{K}'$.